# How to correct the loop with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is an original code:

```
var arrayList = $("td.ms-vb-title:contains('')");
            alert(arrayList.text());
            $.each(arrayList, function (i, e) {
                areaname[i] = $(e).text();
            });
```

**Output**: `alert(arrayList.text());` --> `1  2  3  4  5`

However, my edited code didn't work after modifying...

```
var arrayList = $("td.ms-vb-title:contains('')");
            arrayList = $(arrayList).closest('tbody').find('tr ');
            $(arrayList).each(function () {
                if ($(this).find('td.ms-vb2').eq(1).text() != "") {
                    arrayList = $(this).find('td.ms-vb2').eq(1);
                }
            });
            alert(arrayList.text());
            $.each(arrayList_temp, function (i, e) {
                areaname[i] = $(e).text();
            });
```

**Output**: `alert(arrayList.text());` --> `2,009` **(It should be parallel with `1 2 3 4 5` as `2,004 2,005 2,006 2,007 2,009`)**

**JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/huydq91/CRY5w/2/**

Comment: why? what does your markup look like? what is arrayList_temp?

Comment: What is your problem now? Extend the previous [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B2dG9/1/) and post your requirement

Comment: **@Maurice Perry**, **@Satpal**: Here is the JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/huydq91/CRY5w/ Sorry for this inconvenience that it is quite hard to see. I am heading to get the **`2004 2005 2006 2007 2009`** instead of the original code which outputs **`1 2 3 4 5`**

Comment: **@Maurice Perry**, **@Satpal**: I've updated the library jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/huydq91/CRY5w/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your selectors it would be like:

```
var arrayList = $("td.ms-vb-title:contains('')");
arrayList = arrayList.closest('tbody').find('tr');
var arrayList_temp = null;
$(arrayList).each(function () {
    if ($(this).find('td.ms-vb2').eq(1).text() != "") {
        if (arrayList_temp)
            arrayList_temp = arrayList_temp.add($(this).find('td.ms-vb2').eq(1));
        else
            arrayList_temp = $(this).find('td.ms-vb2').eq(1);
    }
});
alert(arrayList_temp.text());
$.each(arrayList_temp, function (i, e) {
    areaname[i] = $(e).text();
});
```

But I didnt examine your html-structure, because its quite confusing at a first glance. Perhaps there is a better way too...

Comment: Thank you for your code. That works very well, although my code is not clear at all...